# C# локальные функции, производительность

Tags: c#, оптимизация

Всем добрый день, не так давно меня стали терзать мысли по поводу производительности локальных методов, т.к использую их достаточно часто, для организации кода внутри больших методов(Те части кода, которые повторяются внутри метода, но не используются где либо ещё).

```
 void MainMethod()
    {
        void InnerMethod()
        {

        }

    }
```

Собственно вопрос, где, кроме "Gogole.com", можно почитать о полезности, скорости и внутреннем устройстве?

Comment: можно в [devblogs](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/dissecting-the-local-functions-in-c-7/)

Comment: Я бы больше озаботился вопросом модульного тестирования.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, а что с ним не так?

Comment: @Grundy - как тестировать локальные функции? Если встал вопрос производительности, значит они выполняют сложную работу. Значит, их крайне желательно тестировать. Значит, делаем их обычными, а не локальными.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, очевидно никак не тестировать, нужно тестировать метод в котором эти функции объявлены :)

Comment: Напишите кто-нибудь конструктивный ответ, а не коммент. Вопрос то интересный.